# How to create scatter plot using plotly for multiple linear regression from sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, plotly, scatter-plot

There are X_train and y_train. There are 2 variables under X_train. I am using multiple linear regression to train the model. How to create a scatter plot where the x for plotly has 2 variables?

The code looks something like this:

```
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, df.tip)

x_range = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), 100)
y_range = model.predict(x_range.reshape(-1, 1))

fig = px.scatter(df, x='total_bill', y='tip', opacity=0.65)
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x_range, y=y_range, name='Regression Fit'))
fig.show()
```

I had this error:

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with 
gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)-\>(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 1)
```

Comment: Hi, from a cursory look I'm pretty sure that the problem is not with the plotting - but with the model. Please share the line at which the error was produced.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you share your variable `X` or give us enough information to reproduce your problem. Currently we can't run your code because we don't know what `X` looks like